# How to restart java program if JVM crashes

Tags: java, jvm

I am working on a very low configuration machine , where JVM crashes sometimes.

The java application name is application.jar, which plays HD Video from local streaming servers. This application is running on a embeded win7 touch computer, which is hanged in a lounge.

Some time the heap size exceeds and the error is out of memory the the JVM shuts down.

I want to restart my application.jar whenever JVM crashes.

**It is possible. Then how?**

Thanks.

Edit: wrapping with try catch does not work as jvm crashed. 
I also have used -Xms512m -Xmx1024m while running the jar file. the crash frequency is got lower but still it remains.

Comment: From the moment JVM crashes, this stops being a Java question.

Comment: Yes, but it started from the Java and JVM. nevermind.

Comment: Identify the crash cause, fix it. Restarting the JVM is not a good solution IMHO. (If you still want to do it a `while true` around the java call might do the trick)

Comment: What I mean is that if a program halts *unexpectedly*, namely JVM, you can't tell JVM to restart itself because it's at the moment closed. You probably could tell JVM to restart itself before it crashes, though. I think you should have an external program that restarts the app everytime it closes abruptly.

Comment: It crashes due to the low configuration machine With Atom Processor and 1024 DDR2 Ram. Which I can not replace.

Crashes happens once is a week and the application can not to be remain stopped for such long time that some one manually start the application again. :(

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja yes, thinking of something like that. 
That is why wanted to know is there any way.

Comment: To better illustrate my point: You want a person to wake up an hour after he has gone to bed. Normally, the person would set an alarm to go off after one hour just before going to bed, but what if the person fell asleep before he could set the alarm?

Comment: Anyway, an easy solution would be to close and restart the application every day at a predefined time. This would most likely make the JVM's memory consumption drop significantly, leading to it not crashing every week.

Comment: You could write a watchdog script to restart the Java application when it's crashed.

Comment: @Tarik , do you have any suggestion of such script .

Comment: In shell it could be something like `while true; do java -jar app.jar; done`

Comment: Where is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

If really need auto restart you can wrap your application with demonization tool like [daemon](http://www.libslack.org/daemon/). It has `--respawn` parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support Windows :(

Comment: Take a look http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/ I have good expirerance with it and it has windows support.